# jQuery - add several textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using this code:

```
    jQuery.fn.update_textarea = function(test) { 
                $("#articles_textarea").html('');
                for (i=0;i<test;++i) { 
                    if (message[i]) { $("#articles_textarea").html('<textarea></textarea>'); }
                    else { message[i] = ''; $("#articles_textarea").html('<textarea></textarea>'); }
                }
            }
```

When im trying to add more then one, nothing happends but if i add 1 it works just as it should..

This is the "call"code

```
$("#articles_textarea").update_textarea(total);
```

This is variable total:

```
var total = parseFloat($(".testCounter").val()) + 5;
```

This is for calling only one textarea (the part that works):

```
$("#articles_textarea").update_textarea(1);
```

When i call one box it's working when i call several boxes nothing happends at all..

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w5kSk/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with append method. .html() will remove the previous content

```
jQuery.fn.update_textarea = function(test) { 
            $("#articles_textarea").html('');
            for (i=0;i<test;++i) { 
                if (message[i]) { $("#articles_textarea").append('<textarea></textarea>'); }
                else { message[i] = ''; $("#articles_textarea").append('<textarea></textarea>'); }
            }
        }
```

Comment: So obvious.. Thanks for the help even if i should figure out that answer on my own ^^

Comment: @Tommy:if you have found your answer, then please close this question, this would reduce the no of Open Question from SO Open Questions Pool :)

Comment: How to close ? I only know how to mark as right answer

Answer (score 0):

Why you use `jQuery.fn`, when you don't use its functionality, whereas it works, only for the `textarea`s with `articles_textarea` Id, you better do it using a simple function like:

```
function update_textarea(test) { 
    $("#articles_textarea").html('');
    for (var i=0;i<test;++i) { 
        if (!message[i]){
            message[i] = '';
        }
        $("#articles_textarea").append('<textarea></textarea>');
    }
};
```

adding a new function to `jQuery.fn` is used to create new jQuery plugins, check this [link](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/) for more info.
the other point was not using `var i` in your for loop which is not a good practice. Moreover both your if statement and the else, were the same, except `message[i] = '';` part.

BTW if you want to do it using `jQuery.fn`, you better do it like:

```
jQuery.fn.update_textarea = function(test) { 
    this.html('');
    for (var i=0;i<test;++i) { 
        if (!message[i]){
            message[i] = '';
        }
        this.append('<textarea></textarea>');
    }
};
```